# numpy kron along a given axis

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a function for applying the Kronecker product along a given axis? For example, given 2D arrays `a` and `b` of shapes `a.shape == (n, k)` and `b.shape == (n, l)`, compute `c` of shape `c.shape == (n, k*l)` with the equivalent result of:

```
c = np.empty((a.shape[0], a.shape[1] * b.shape[1]))
for i in range(c.shape[0]):
    c[i,:] = np.kron(a[i], b[i])
```

Comment: Can you look at `np.kron` code?  I don't recall if it is compiled or python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a built-in, but we can use `outer elementwise-multiplication` keeping their first axis aligned and then reshape -

```
c = (a[:,:,None]*b[:,None,:]).reshape(a.shape[0],-1)
```

Alternatively, we can use `einsum` -

```
c = np.einsum('nk,nl->nkl',a,b).reshape(a.shape[0],-1)
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. Love the einsum solution, it's such a versatile tool.

Answer (score 0):

In case sparsity is desired:

```
from scipy.sparse import kron


def kron_prod_in_axis1(a, b):
    return kron(a, b, format="csr")[[i * a.shape[0] + i for i in range(a.shape[0])], :]
```